# How to modify a vs code command in an extension command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an extension for Visual Studio Code that makes the Touch Bar on my Macbook Pro a little bit more useful. In order to accomplish some of my goals for this extension I'd like to be able to modify the icon of a command at run time.

However I have a hard time figuring out how to do that. To bring it back to the most basic example:

in my `extension.ts`

```ts
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.openX', () => {
  // Here i'd like to do something with the command that was fired, like for example modify the icon or title
  vscode.commands.getCommands().then((commands) => {
    console.log(commands);
  });
};
```

In my `package.json`

```json
"contributes": {
  "commands": [
    {
      "command": "extension.openX",
      "title": "Open X",
      "icon": "./assets/ci.png"
    }
  ],
  "menus": {
    "touchBar": [
      {
        "command": "extension.openX",
        "group": "ci"
      }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this or would I need to work with adding a bunch of different commands with specific icons and using the `"when"` option in order to show the right icon at the right time?

I'd prefer to avoid this because I'd preferably make the amount of different possible states dynamic based on some external API.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this or would I need to work with adding a bunch of different commands with specific icons and using the `"when"` option in order to show the right icon at the right time?

Right now, your only option is indeed using `"when"` in combination with [`setContext()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893369/2631715). There is a related (albeit closed as "out of scope") feature request here:

[Allow extensions to override command title and/or icon in menu placement (in package.json)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34048)