# Is there a way to disable a command-emitting button in a view panel and grey it out if a condition is not met?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VS Code extension, and have a custom view which contains a tree view which shows a list of projects.

[image]

I'd like to make it so that the triangle button is greyed out if the list of projects is empty.

I feel like this should be possible, since there are plenty of instances of this behavior in the `Explorer` and `Search` views, but there seems to be nothing in the extension API that allows me to implement it in my own extension.

I found the `Action` class in VS Code's source code that has the `enabled` flag, which seems to be something close to what I need. I can't however find anything relevant in the extension API in `vscode.d.ts`, or any means of accessing these classes that appear in VS Code's source.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`enablement` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35#_extension-authoring) in `package.json` when defining your command:

```json
{
    "title": "Run",
    "command": "lgtm.run",
    "enablement": "hasLgtmProjects"
}
```

You would then need to dynamically update the `hasLgtmProjects` context key from your extension using the [`setContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852670/adding-conditions-to-when-from-vs-code-extension/44893369#44893369) command.