# VSCode Extension API - Can we add conditional context menus in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension that contains a context menu on the explorer. I need to show these items based on a condition which involves complex logic. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: You can use a `when` clause with `setContext`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852670/adding-conditions-to-when-from-vs-code-extension

Comment: Tried this but can't get it to work. I added `commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'test.key', true);` in my activate function and the when clause is `explorerResourceIsFolder && test.key`.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure your extension is being activated?

Comment: Yes. What should be the event I should set the context in to set when the workspace is loaded to explorer?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the activation event you should use? Depends on what your extension does exactly, but for debugging you could use `*` to make sure it's not that. Or add a log / breakpoint to make sure that code is being executed.

Comment: Got it to work after changing the activation event to *

Comment: Is there a way I can configure only one activation event to work at start up without using *?

Comment: onView:explorer might work?