# VSCode: Keybindings only in certain 'modes'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In emacs you can (de)activate certain modes while working on a file (buffer).  For example, you could set up keyboard shortcuts but only when a particular mode is active.  This way you can have keyboard shortcuts that only apply when editing, say, JavaScript files, or when you choose to start up a mode.

I'd like to do something similar for VSCode.  I've written an extension and I'd like to replace a bunch of keybindings but only when I've activated the extension.  This way I can use F3, F4, F5 normally, but can then switch to my keybindings manually, so that those keybindings now run code in my extension instead of their 'normal' ones.

I've seen VSCode keymaps but they appear to change everything all the time (so that VSCode acts like vim, or Sublime, etc, etc).

Any ideas / advice on where to look to find out how a VSCode extension can install keybindings, but only after being told to install them?

Comment: You can use `setContext` for custom `when` conditions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852670/adding-conditions-to-when-from-vs-code-extension/44893369#44893369

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks!