# VSCode Extensions: How to enable/disable view based on globalState

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension and I want a `WebViewView` in the activity bar to only be displayed when the user isn't logged in. To store the state of the user, I use the `globalState` API. How can I access the globalState from a `when` clause in the extension manifest?

Comment: You can't, but you can invoke `setContext` based on the global state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893369/2631715

Comment: Oh :(. That's sad to hear? Do you know why we can't just use the globalState?

Comment: I imagine that wouldn't really work because context keys are shared, while the global state is "private" to each extension.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to put your comments as an answer, I will happily mark it as the correct answer!